# Math to obtain a color scale variation in decimal

Tags: hsv

I am trying to find a math that makes possible a correct calculation of a color (HSV) scale variation like:

Color blue = #002AFF (in hexadecimal) = 11007 (in decimal)
This color blue has Hue = 230, 100% saturation and 100% value.

So I need to make a scale that contains X blue colors (in this example) variations from 50% saturation to 100% saturation, and after that, from 100% value to 50% of value (while 100% saturation).

Example:
blue(99% saturation, 100% value) == 142591 in decimal
blue(98% saturation, 100% value) == 339711 in decimal

In order to make that scale, I need that this math returns me a decimal value of each color generated out of that color math, so Ill use the decimal value within my program to generate the rgb color.

So do you guys knows any code able to do this math? Cause I can't just figure out a math for it